# How to combine two HTML documents?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have two HTML documents. The 1st one will show the table which consists of data. The second code is which will download the data.

How can I insert the second code into first one?

I'm attaching the 1st html code below

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <!--link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename='images/favicon.ico')}}"-->

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Datatable -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/dataRender/datetime.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form method="post">
<!--          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="user_csv"></textarea>-->
          <button class="btn btn-success mt-2">Show output data</button>
        </form>
        <div class="mt-4">
          {% if request.method == 'POST'%}
            <table id="proxies" class="display table nowrap responsive" style="width: 100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  {% for header in results[0].keys() %}
                    <th>{{header}}</th>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for row in results %}
                  <tr>
                    {% for index in range(0, len(fieldnames)) %}
                      <td>{{row[fieldnames[index]]}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#proxies').DataTable();
  </script>

</html>
```

And the screenshot for the above html is

[image]

2nd html code is below, which will download the data

```
<h2>Download the output data</h2>
<p>
<a href="{{url_for('download_file')}}">Download</a>
</p>
```

And the screenshot for the above html is

[image]

My expected output screenshot is below

[image]

**How to combine the two codes?**

Comment: Please include only the relevant information to your question, and change the title to a more descriptive and concise title, to help people understand what it is exactly you need help with.

Comment: What is a "code" here? A file? Data in memory? Your question isn't clear.

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, I would use Jquery to include the other HTML file, like so below:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

you could also just include the <a attribute as a button in the first file?

Comment: the other answer i submitted to you, would give you a button.

Answer (score -2):

I would go with the last option i offered: example with code

Here I'm using the HTML attribute => button and wrap the anchor tag  around it

```
              <tbody>
                {% for row in results %}
                  <tr>
                    {% for index in range(0, len(fieldnames)) %}
                      <td>{{row[fieldnames[index]]}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<-- Here is it included below !-->
     <div>
<h2>Download the data</h2>
<a href="{{url_for('download_file')}}"><button>Download</button></a>
</div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A button has no business inside an anchor. That's a violation of HTML spec and good UX.